# split data table to small tables R

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a following table (more than 1k rows):

```
  x1      x2  x3  x4 
7809  243638   1   1 
7809  243638   1   1
7809  243638   1   1 
... 
3453  222222   1   0
```

and I need to split this table to small tables (which will be in my environment as data frames) based on 2nd column `x2`.
I've tried to do `split(dat,dat$x2)` and R did it right but in list.

Comment: As you yourself said "R did it **right** but in **list**". R indeed did it right and kept it in a list format because polluting your global environment with numerous data set is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

if you do

```
split_list <- split(dat,dat$x2)
```

you can access the splitted results with

```
split_list[[1]]
split_list[[2]]
....
```

to convert a result

```
# to a data.frame
df1 <- as.data.frame(split_list[[1]])

# to a table
t1 <- as.table(split_list[[1]])
```

to store in multiple data sets (even though I don't see the benefit of it)

```
names1 <- names(split_list)

for(i in seq_along(names1)){
  assign(names1[i], split_list[[i]])
}
```

Comment: got it, and how to cycle it for more than 700 results?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974260/assign-list-of-data-to-variables-in-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is a bit older. I came across a similar problem recently and want to share the code still.

I wanted to split a `data.table` in equally sized chunks. The number of chunks I computed beforehand by dividing the total number of rows of the `data.table` by the number of smaller `data.table`s I intended to receive. I wrote a function that splits the `data.table` (input `x`) into the number of chunks with equal number of rows (`no_rows_per_frame`) and put a path were to store the frames (`path_to_store`).

I needed it to handcollect variables for the chunks. But you could rewrite it to simply return all `data.table`s separately. Or better and according to @David Arenburg's answer: Store it in a list and don't pollute your global environment. NB: The code might not be efficient as it uses a loop, but was pretty fast for my sample containing almost 500k observations (as `data.table` is).

```
# function: split into equally-sized samples for handcollection
split_data_table <- function(x, no_rows_per_frame, path_to_store){

  split_vec <- seq(1, nrow(x), no_rows_per_frame)

  for (split_cut in split_vec) {
    sample <- x[split_cut:(split_cut+(no_rows_per_frame-1))]
    fwrite(sample, paste(path_to_store, "sample_until_", (split_cut+(no_rows_per_frame-1)), ".csv", sep = ""))
  }
}

# apply sample cut
split_data_table(x = vendor_tab, no_rows_per_frame = 5000, 
                 path_to_store = "C/...")
```

Hope it help so.!